# How to inherit class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new to VB and I want to inherit from `DataGridView`, I use something like

```
Public Class DataGridViewEx Inherits DataGridView
End Class
```

But compiler generates an error as `End of statement expected` pointing to `Inherits DataGridView`. What is wrong and how I should do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it in the next line:

```
Public Class DataGridViewEx 
    Inherits DataGridView
End Class
```

[MSDN: **Inherits**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1yk8s7sk.aspx)

> If used, the Inherits statement must be the first non-blank,
>   non-comment line in a class or interface definition. It should
>   immediately follow the Class or Interface statement.

Comment: So much thanks, I read the help on microsoft web site just after asking the question.

Comment: This works too: `Public Class DataGridViewEx : Inherits DataGridView`

Answer (score -1):

declared on the first line after the class,
You can use Inherits only in a class or interface. This means the declaration context for an inheritance cannot be a source file, namespace, structure, module, procedure, or block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/inherits-statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).